# How to make the date appear next to the time indicator in Gnome Classic?

Tags: indicator, gnome-classic

I'm using Gnome classic in Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm not able to find the settings that would allow me to display the date and day along with time in the clock of my indicator applet. Any idea how I can make the date and day appear along with the time?

When I click on the clock and then click on "Time and Date settings", I get the "System settings". From there when I click on "Date and time", I get a setting where I can just edit the date and time. I'm using 12.04 with Gnome classic. I removed unity.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using `dconf-editor` you can set various options to control the indicator-datetime applet

[image]

Navigate to com.canonical.indicator.datetime and tick the two checkboxes shown.

`dconf-editor` is part of the `dconf-tools` package which you can install from the Software Center or via a terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

If the date does not appear then check that you have the [indicator-datetime](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-datetime) package installed (logoff and logon after installing the package)

[image: Install indicator-datetime]

Later versions of Ubuntu sometimes do not show the path shown in the picture.  You'll need to manually set one of the keys first before the path is shown in `dconf-editor`

For example:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-clock true
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-day true
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-date true
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very nicely written answer. I installed dconf-tools and have got the day and date along with the time using the gconf-editor.

Comment: It's sort of dumb not to include the date by default. I am not trying to sound hash, but it is true. But thanks for the tips!

Comment: is there any way to add the year too? I don't see any options

Comment: It's especially dumb that you have to be root for just a simple setting like this since dconf-editor is not part of the default installation.

Comment: And if you want to show the date, but *not* the time, you have to set `time-format` to custom and change `custom-time-format` to something like `%F %A` (full y-m-d date, and day-of-week). This gives complete flexibility over what to show. See `man date` for more on how that works.