# Unity Clock Missing

Tags: unity

I recently installed ubuntu 12.10 and it seems as though my clock is missing. I also don't see any options for date/time in the system settings panel.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something? Again this is with Unity.

Comment: in my case it was running but bugged, I could not change settings and so; I did `pkill -f indicator-datetime` and it instantly worked again!

Comment: @AquariusPower This worked for me as well too under 14.04 LTS. Thanks

Comment: That worked for me also under 14.04. I guess the clock is just buggy.

Comment: none of the solutions worked for my unbuntu16 where my clock disappeared after some automatic update.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be one of two things, either the clock isn't installed, or a setting has been flipped to turn it off.

First make sure the clock is installed by making sure indicator-datetime is installed:

[image: Install via the software center]

Then log out and back in. If it's already installed and it's still not showing up, try the options here:

- [How to make the date appear next to the time indicator in Gnome Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129985/how-to-make-the-date-appear-next-to-the-time-indicator-in-gnome-classic)

If that still doesn't work update your question with the results, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the hints! A simple sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime fixed the problem!

Answer (score 105):

As per the comments above I've fixed this issue on my brand new 14.04 LTS installation by running.

```
$ pkill -f indicator-datetime-service
```

The clock came straight back.

Comment: interesting, none of the other tips worked for me, this did. thx.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (At least if the question were for 14.04.4 LTS.)

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Shell-only answers deserve extra points.

Answer (score 17):

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then run the following:

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

This command should reset the panel, and hopefully reactivate the clock indicator.

Comment: To make it more convinient you can also create an alias in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`. 
 
 `alias restart-clock="killall unity-panel-service"`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

and logout/login.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/357280/25184

Comment: No need for `sudo` before `killall`.

Comment: In my case `killall unity-panel-service` was enough to bring the clock back.

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 14.04.