# How to show time in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: indicator

Just upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10.

Everything went fine but I don't see the time in the top right corner of the 'top bar' anymore. I tried to right click on it so I could get some options but nothings shows.

I'm sure it's obvious but I don't see it.

Comment: I think you have hit a bug.

Comment: I think I did...

Comment: Did you ever file a bug report? I'm now experiencing this myself.

Comment: This is not "problems with the development version of Ubuntu" - I upgraded to the official release of 13.10 experienced the same problem. Maybe it's a bug though.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Already solved [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1648637) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-from-top-panel-of-unity-desktop).
From the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Then logout & login from the graphic session.
If the clock is still hidden/grayed out:

[image: Time&Date panel --> Clock --> Show a clock in the menu bar]

If it still doesn't work report a bug [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/indicator-datetime).
*edited to solve a bigger slice of problems.

Comment: It was already installed, purged and reinstalled but the clock panel under data/time is still greyd out.

Comment: I edited the post, try to follow this new procedure. If it still doesn't work write it to help the others. ;-)

Comment: 13.10 here, bingo. It works.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me on 13.10 - the panel you show above is greyed out for me.

Comment: For me, indicator-datetime was already installed after the upgrade. The last two commands solved the issue though, thanks.

Comment: works, thanks after this the Time & Date => Clock Settings were enabled

Comment: no need to login / logout.  fixed automatically.  tks UPVOTED :)

Comment: works like a charm in 14.04

Answer (score 3):

Go to Time & Date under System Settings, and after you click on it, click on the Clock tab, and make sure that there is a check mark in Show a clock in the menu bar.  See image below.

[image]

Edit on behalf of @user221931
If the whole panel is grayed out, try (as mentioned already in another answer) the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata && sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: The entire panel is greyed out

Comment: If the whole panel is grayed out, try (as mentioned already in another answer) the following commands in a terminal:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
&& sudo killall unity-panel-service`

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center`. If it is un-installed, install it. Then for date-time install the package `indicator-datetime`.