# No Time in Top Panel (Gnome Classic)

Tags: indicator, panel, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, clock

I've been using Ubuntu with Gnome Classic for a while and I've noticed recently that in the "Indicator Applet Complete" in the Top Panel, my name and the clock have disappeared.

[image: pic]

I **think** it happened a while ago when I was messing around with packages. Every time I did `apt-get`... it would say "`the following packages can be removed by apt-get autoremove`", so I did it and then the clock and my name stopped appearing.

Can anyone help me? Thanks. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/129985/how-to-make-the-date-appear-next-to-the-time-indicator-in-gnome-classic?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reinstall indicator-datetime.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime

sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Reboot .

[image]

Comment: my pleasure mate , happy to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

install dconf editor

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
gksu dconf-editor
```

goto com >> canonical>> indicators >> datetime and tick show clock

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to run `dconf-editor` as root with `gksu`... just running `dconf-editor` should be fine.